# calling method from another class C#

Tags: c#, class, methods, call

I have this method, which has to insert some data into my database

```
public Zakaznik_Mapper()
        {


        public bool Insert(int ID_zakaznik, String Name, String LastName, String Login, String Password, int Number, String Email, String Adress)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                tran = conn.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.Serializable);
                SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Zakaznik VALUES (@ID_zakaznik, @Name, @LastName, @Login, @Password, @Number, @Email, @Adress );", conn, tran);
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ID_zakaznik", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = ID_zakaznik });
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = Name });
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@LastName", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = LastName });
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Login", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = Login });
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Password", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = Password });
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Number", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = Number });
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = Email });
                insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Adress", SqlDbType.VarChar) { Value = Adress });

                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                tran.Commit();
                conn.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                conn.Close();
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

and i want to call method Insert from UlozZakaznik(), but i am getting error type "No overload for method 'Insert' takes 0 arguments" If someone could help with it i would be so happy :)

```
 public void UlozZakaznik()
    {
        DataTable data_zakaznik = new DataTable("Zakazka");
        data_zakaznik.Columns.Add("ID_Zakaznik");
        data_zakaznik.Columns.Add("Name");
        data_zakaznik.Columns.Add("Lastname");
        data_zakaznik.Columns.Add("Login");
        data_zakaznik.Columns.Add("Password");
        data_zakaznik.Columns.Add("Number");
        data_zakaznik.Columns.Add("Email");
        data_zakaznik.Columns.Add("Adress");

        Zakaznik_Mapper zakaznik = new Zakaznik_Mapper();

        Zakaznik zakaznik1 = new Zakaznik();
        zakaznik1.ID_zakaznik = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[0].Value);
        zakaznik1.Name = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[1].Value);
        zakaznik1.LastName = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[2].Value);
        zakaznik1.Login = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[3].Value);
        zakaznik1.Password = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[4].Value);
        zakaznik1.Number = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[5].Value);
        zakaznik1.Email = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[6].Value);
        zakaznik1.Adress = Convert.ToString(dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[7].Value);

        if (dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[0].Value != null
            && dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[1].Value != null
            && dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[2].Value != null 
            && dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[3].Value != null
            && dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[4].Value != null
            && dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[5].Value != null
            && dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[6].Value != null
            && dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.RowCount - 2].Cells[7].Value != null
            )
        {
            data_zakaznik.Rows.Add(zakaznik1.ID_zakaznik, zakaznik1.Name, zakaznik1.LastName, zakaznik1.Login, zakaznik1.Password, zakaznik1.Number, zakaznik1.Email, zakaznik1.Adress);

            zakaznik.Insert();//problem is here "Error type: No overload for method 'Insert' takes 0 arguments"

        }
    }
```

Comment: The error is telling you what the problem is; the only method signature that exists for insert is `public bool Insert(int ID_zakaznik, String .....other parameters)` either supply the parameters, define an insert that takes no arguments, or provide default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is as clear as it gets, you can't just call it without passing it data, it's expecting a certain amount of parameters so you must pass them.

Is this for work or school or just a hobby? If it's for work/School you should contact whoever is in charge for you and ask for some in depth advice as you really need to sit a few hours and learn around it.

However in your specific case i assume what you're looking for is replacing

```
zakaznik.Insert();
```

with

```
zakaznik.Insert(zakaznik1.ID_zakaznik, zakaznik1.Name, zakaznik1.LastName, zakaznik1.Login, zakaznik1.Password, zakaznik1.Number, zakaznik1.Email, zakaznik1.Adress);
```

Comment: its for school, i am learning when i got time but sometimes i am making so stupid mistakes like this even when i got the the resolution on my eyes. I put zakaznik.Insert(zakaznik.ID_zakaznik...) thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

You need to provide arguments for you function.

Here:

```
public bool Insert(int ID_zakaznik, 
                   String Name, 
                   String LastName, 
                   String Login, 
                   String Password, 
                   int Number, 
                   String Email, 
                   String Adress)
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ arguments
```

The function expects you to pass it something to work with.

So this:

```
zakaznik.Insert();
```

Should be something like:

```
zakaznik.Insert(id_here, name_here, last_name_here, ..., ..., ...); // etc
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you exactly what you're doing wrong.  Your Insert() method requires 8 arguments, but you're providing 0.